# Create yuv mat in opencv on android

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, yuv

I am implementing computer vision project for Android and I am using OpenCV with Android NDK for it. It receives data in YUV NV21 format from camera in byte array from PreviewCallback and calls native part of app. 
My problem is, that I don't know, how to create 3-channel Mat with YUV data to do thresholding on it.
For thresholding I want to use this code

```
Mat* threshold = new Mat(height, width, CV_8UC1);    
Scalar low(yuvPixel[0] - 50, yuvPixel[1] - 10, yuvPixel[2] - 10);
Scalar up(yuvPixel[0] + 50, yuvPixel[1] + 10, yuvPixel[2] + 10);
inRange(image, low, up, *threshold);
```

I only know, how to create 1-channel Mat using

```
Mat image(height + height/2, width, CV_8UC1, (unsigned char *)frameData);
```

Is there any simple way to convert this Mat to 3-channel Mat?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

to create 3-channel Mat with YUV data.

```
   Mat myuv(height + height/2, width, CV_8UC1, (unsigned char *)_yuv);
```

for a yuv 422 data. the things is matching your yuv data format carefully.

"Is there any simple way to convert this Mat to 3-channel Mat?"

did you mean 3-channel RGB data? if so, following codes should work

```
 //
Mat myuv(height + height/2, width, CV_8UC1, ( unsigned char *)_yuv);
Mat mbgra(height, width, CV_8UC4, ( unsigned char *)_bgra);
Mat mgray(height, width, CV_8UC1, ( unsigned char *)_yuv);

 //
cvtColor(myuv, mbgra, CV_YUV420sp2BGR, 4);
```